# How to call a method whenever I move the mouse or press a key on the keyboard?

Tags: c#, winforms

i am working in C# win forms and iam monitoring process idle time out(eg: notepad,skype) whenever i move or press mouse or keyboard a **function** has to be called so then ill write the current time in a log file.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: i want a function[eg: KeyboardKeyPressed() ] to be called whenever i press a key in keyboard

Comment: You can check for windows hooks if you need to track all keyboard and mouse events

Comment: Search for Global mouse and keyboard hooks

Comment: i used user32.dll for sethook & call hook its working upto 3 times after that its not working.when i pressed the keyboard key for 3 times the methods gets called after tht when i pressed for the 4th time its not working

Comment: You need to show the code you wrote that is not working by editing your question to show it.

Comment: i need to monitor globally for example im monitoring notepad i minimised it then iam in skype and im gone for sometime like 10 min after that when i press a key a function has to be called.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the designer view of the form, select the properties of the form and in the properties window click the event button (that looks like a lightning bolt), there double click on the `MouseMove` event and `KeyDown` event. Call your method from both of these events.

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       MyMethod();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       MyMethod();
    }
```

Comment: i need to monitor globally for example im monitoring notepad i minimised it then iam in skype and im gone for sometime like 10 min after that when i press a key a function has to be called.

Comment: Take a look at this link, I think this is what you are looking for `https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/`

Answer (score 0):

If override `OnPreviewKeyDown` in a form code-behind file, you will get the keyboard key pressed event when the form is focused.

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}
```

If you want to get the keyboard key pressed event when the form is focused or not you can use below class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KeyLogger
{    
    public delegate void KeyRecievedArg(int key);
    public class KeyboardListener
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError =true)]  
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        public static event KeyRecievedArg KeyRecieved;

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
             if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
             {
                 int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                 KeyRecieved(vkCode);
             }           
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
        public static void OnClosed()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }
        public static void OnOpen()
        {
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        }        
    }
}
```